# Make a program end when user input a certain sentence

Tags: c

Anyone knows how can i make my program stop after user inputs the sentence "this is the end"?
My code is like this: 
also ignore any foreign words :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main ()
{
    char sent[100];
    int i,len;
    do {
    printf("Dose mia protasi :\n");/*Edo to programa zitaei tin protasi*/
    gets(sent);
    len=strlen(sent);
    printf("*");


    for(i=0;i<len;i++)/*edo ginete i proti epanalipsi gia na ektiponei tous asteriskous*/
        {
            printf("**");
        }
        printf("\n*");

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)/* edo stin for  bazeis afto p lei sent[i]=sent[i]-32; kai pernei apo ton pinaka ascii anti gia mikira mono kefalea*/
    {

        if (sent[i]>='a' && sent[i]<='z'){
{
    sent[i]=sent[i]-32;// Edo pernei ta mikra gramata kai ta kanei kefalea
}
           printf("%c*",sent[i]);/*edo ektiponei tous xaraktires me asteriskous meta ton kathe xaraktira*/
        }
        else if(sent[i]>='1' && sent[i]<='9')
                printf("H protasi dn einai apodekti xanaprospathise");
    }

    printf("\n*");
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            printf("**");
        }printf("\n");
}while();/*<<<<-------NEED TO FIX THIS that when user inputs the sentence this is the end the program stops */

    }
```

The code is on C.
Thank you

Comment: If you want us to ignore all the foreign words, why even bother posting any code at all?

Answer (score 0):

here's a piece of code that could do the trick :

```
char sentence[100];
fgets(sentence , sizeof sentence , stdin);
if(!strcmp(sentence , "this is the end?"))
     exit(0);
```

**Edit :**

after the `fgets` you'll have to remove the newline from `sentence` in order for this to work here's a function that does that :

```
int i = 0;
   for(i = strlen(sentence) ; i > 0 ; i--)
       if(sentence[i] == '\n')
           sentence[i] = '\0';
```

don't forget to include `string.h`

Comment: where ever you want to check if the user wants to leave